# QT - How To Move A File

Tags: c++, qt

I want to replace a file on my drive with another file. After doing research I discovered that there is no 'replace' method. Instead, I would have to delete my original file, then move my temporary file into its place. When I do this, I don't see my updated temporary file being moved into its new directory.

```
QTemporaryFile tempFile;
if (tempFile.open())
{
    // Create temp file
    QTextStream stream;
    stream.setDevice(&tempFile);
    document.save(stream, 4); // document is a QDomDocument object
    tempFile.close();

    // Replace original file with temp file
    file.remove();
    tempFile.rename("C:\\ProgramData\\Foo\\data.xml"); // I don't see the updated data.xml
}
```

Comment: Make sure that the path in program code is correct. I recall that worked for me.

Comment: This is a classical XY Problem. Even though the question is a literal duplicate of another one, you don't really care about renaming at all. What you're looking for is `QSaveFile`. It ensures that the operation is atomic: either the writes succeed and the file is replaced, or the original file is retained without change. The temporary files and atomic magic are handled for you in a platform-independent way. Win-win.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue seems to come from using `QTemporaryFile`.

First, note that `tempFile.close();` does nothing.
From Qt code:

```
bool QTemporaryFileEngine::close()
{
    // Don't close the file, just seek to the front.
    seek(0);
    setError(QFile::UnspecifiedError, QString());
    return true;
}
```

Second, when you call `tempFile.rename("C:\\ProgramData\\Foo\\data.xml");`,
 it will effectively close the `tempFile`, but it will also change `tempFile.fileName()` which means that when the `tempFile` object gets deleted, it will delete the file you copied to. If you want to prevent this you can call `tempFile.setAutoRemove(false)`

Another solution for what you are trying to do is to use [QSaveFile](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsavefile.html) which handles the "save to temp/close/replace" routine for you.

Comment: I would have also recommended `QSaveFile` as that is exactly the use case it was created for

Comment: `QSaveFile` isn't just "another solution". It is *the* solution, but the asker has pigeonholed themselves by presuming a solution instead of describing the more general problem (that of an atomic save that doesn't corrupt data).